# Uncaught Exception: Unable to locate Mix file

Tags: php, laravel, webpack

I am trying to run a laravel app in my local system. I have followed the https://gist.github.com/hootlex/da59b91c628a6688ceb1 link. I run the command **php artisan serve** command, and when I browse it, then produces the error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Unable to locate Mix file: /css/vendor.css. Please check your webpack.mix.js output paths and try again. in /var/www/html/laravel-app/app/helpers.php:439
```

In the specified line of helpers.php, it has

```
 if (! isset($manifest[$path])) {
        throw new Exception(
            "Unable to locate Mix file: {$path}. Please check your ".
            'webpack.mix.js output paths and try again.'
        );
    }
```

**public/mix-manifest.json**

```
{
  "/mix.js": "/mix.js"
}
```

I couldn't sort it out. Please help. Thanks

Comment: run command composer update

Comment: How did you accomplish this step? 
> Pull Laravel/php project from git provider.

Comment: I have pulled a project which is developed in php Laravel

Comment: I have executed the commad **composer update** , but is showing the same error.

Comment: The error message shows clearly what is missing. Frontend is build by webpack inside this project. Check the requirements of webpack. Inside the `webpack.mix.js` you will see, that a path is given to `/css/vendor.css` may this file be missing in your folder?

Answer (score 13):

This happened with me and after spending quite some time and effort, I did manage to figure out what was happening and how to fix it.

Here's what happens:

- You update your `webpack.mix.js` file with the destination where you wish to publish your compiled JS and CSS files respectively.

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue();
```

- Mix compiles and stores the hence generated CSS and JS files within their respective destination folders when you run `npm run dev` or `npm run watch`.

```
laravel-app (Your laravel app root folder)
    \public
        \css
            \app.css
        \js
            \app.js
```

- When you open the application in your browser with, say Valet, Laravel spits out the following error message:

```
Unable to locate Mix file: /js/app.js
(or)
Unable to locate Mix file: /css/app.css
```

**Something worth noting on the Uncaught Exception screen though, is that Laravel by default attempts to look for the files at `localhost:8080`. Implied that Laravel is looking for the files respectively at:**

```
localhost:8080\css\app.css
(and)
localhost:8080\js\app.js
```

Hence, if your hostname or port is anything other than `localhost:8080`, Laravel would not be able to find your files. For example, if you're using Valet, your default URL would become `laravel-app.test` where laravel-app is the name of your app's root folder.

But, there's a way to fix this. And it comes directly out to [Laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#custom-mix-base-urls).

#### Solution (TL;DR)

In order to use a custom mix base URL, you would require to update your `config\app.php` file to add the following configuration value for setting the mix URL:

```
'mix_url' => env('MIX_ASSET_URL', 'localhost'),
```

With your `mix_url` config option set in your `app.php` file, you should now be able to manipulate it by adding the `MIX_ASSET_URL` key in your `.env` file and setting it to blank, so that it points to `\public\js\app.js` and \public\css\app.css respectively, within your project directory.

```
MIX_ASSET_URL=""
```

That solved it for me. Hope it does it for your too. Lemme know how it goes. Cheers!

Comment: I did your solution, but I face the error: "Unable to locate Mix file: ...\index.blade.php". what should i do now?

Answer (score 10):

The blade file you're loading obviously has `mix('/css/vendor.css')` call. You either comment out this line(s) or install npm then build your assets.

Your manifest file doesn't have `/css/vendor.css` but if you check your blade files (`views`) you'll see you are calling `mix('/css/vendor.css')`. So if you find and comment out this line(s) your problem will be solved.

Ideally, `mix()` is used for loading assets that were built by webpack. It will then take care of the versioning string for you. How [mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix) can be used is detailed in the documentation. I will refrain myself from discussing that here.

You've built your assets by running `npm run dev` or similar commands. And then the manifest file doesn't contain those assets mapping. And your `public` directory doesn't have those assets as well. Then it's safe to assume that you can remove those `mix` calls from your blade (`views`) files.

If you have the assets built in your `public` directory then you can load those assets by `assets` function.

Lastly, you should know your assets first, before loading them to your site. I get the notion that you don't have any clue where those assets came from, so you shouldn't load them in the first place.

Comment: And built your assets? `npm run dev`

Comment: Could you please show the `mix-manifest.json` file? It should be in your `public` directory.

Comment: See, your manifest file doesn't have `/css/vendor.css` but if you check your blade files (views) you'll see you are calling `mix('/css/vendor.css')`. So if you find and comment out this line(s) your problem will be solved.

Comment: yes, you have exactly spot on. In one of blade file there is css/vendor.css, css/app.css, js/vendor.js, ... What is those lines for? Will it make any issue if I comment those lines?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: The files like vendor.css, app.css are not present, ie why its showing error. As Adre said I have removed the css files from the blade file and is now is excecuting, but css is missing

Answer (score 2):

Try running `npm install`  and after that build the assets, either `npm run dev` or `npm run watch` , depends on what you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to reinstall packages

1. Delete package-lock.json.
2. Delete folder 'node_modules' and run 'npm install' to reinstall all modules.
3. Then run 'npm run watch' or 'npm run production' or ...etc... (build it)

That can help to fix that problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case,
laravel 9
I should have changed the mix-manifest.json file

```
  "/js/application.js": "/js/application.js",
  "/js/admin.js": "/js/admin.js",
  "/css/application.css": "/css/application.css",
  "/css/admin.css":"/css/admin.css"
```

Answer (score 1):

In My case, I change
'debug' => false, to **true**
in the file app.config under config folder in my project to see log in my browser. Then when I run my project got error above like you. then I change to
'debug' => false again. It works.

Answer (score 0):

check the `package.json` file for the command to build the scripts and styles, normally you will have by default: `npm run dev`. Might happen that you will need to run:

- `npm rebuild node-sass`
- `npm run dev` or `npm run watch`

Answer (score 0):

I changed my webpack.mix.js files and made these changes there and worked. Only define the specific path to public/js/app.js in webpack.mix.js

```
mix.js(
    [
        "resources/assets/js/jquery.js",
        "resources/assets/js/popper.js",
        "resources/js/app.js",
    ],
    "public/js/app.js"
)
    .autoload({
        jquery: ["jquery", "jQuery", "$", "window.jQuery"],
        Popper: ["popper", "Popper", "popper.js"],
        popper: ["Popper", "popper.js"],
    })
    .vue()
    .postCss("resources/css/app.css", "public/css", [])
    .sass("resources/sass/app.scss", "public/css")
    .disableNotifications(); // to disable notifications of building app;
```